# Clover code coverage: product's client jar is having 0 coverage

Tags: java, clover

My application is have a app-server.jar in my application server, and a app-client.jar in my test env's classpath. I have both the app-server.jar and app-client.jar instrumented, but after I have executed my tests, I found that there is no coverage of app-client.jar.

Both of my tests and application server run on the same host, and the clover.db is accessible to both test and server.

Am I configuring clover right? what could be causing the 0 coverage of my app-client.jar? Thanks very much in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: Do you have tests for app-client.jar?

Comment: Yes, my tests uses the APIs that app-client.jar provides to connect to server.

Answer (score 0):

Clover fails to record code coverage in case when it's unable to open the clover.db database file. This usually happens when the clover.db file cannot be found - you shall see proper error message in application log, like:

```
CLOVER: Unable to load the coverage database at "<path>"
CLOVER: No coverage data will be gathered.
```

By default Clover use relative path to clover.db file. So in case when you run your application from a different working directory (than the build workspace) it will fail to locate the file.

You an either use absolute path in "inistring" or provide

```
-Dclover.initstring=path/to/clover.db
```

runtime property.

References:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/JVM+properties